# How to force box-shadow & border to back of z-index

Tags: html, css

I have the following...

[image]

...and I'd like to get it looking like this:

[image]

i.e. forcing the box-shadow & border of both the title and subheading to the back, and then moving the title element itself to be above the z-index of the subheading.

I have no idea how to do this- messing around with the z-index on both elements hasn't resulted in any change whatsoever. I'm not even sure how to just get the title in front of the subheading.

```css
h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.boxy {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  box-shadow: -10px -10px;
}
```

```html
<h1><span class="boxy">title</span></h1>
<h3><span class="boxy">subheading blah blah blah</span></h3>
```

Comment: Add position relative on both and repeat z-index experiment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make certain layouts more specific. I used a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to put the headers below each other and to assign horizontal alignment to the center. Hope this helps.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center; /* Horizontal alignment */
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

h1>.boxy {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px 4px 0 4px; /* No border at the bottom */
  box-shadow: -10px -10px;
}

h3>.boxy {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  box-shadow: -10px -10px;
}

.boxy {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1><span class="boxy">title</span></h1>
  <h3><span class="boxy">subheading blah blah blah</span></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use contain the two headings in `display: flex` as shown in the snippet below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

h1,
h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.boxy {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  box-shadow: -10px -10px;
}

h1 .boxy {
  border-bottom: none !important;
  padding-bottom: 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="title">

      <h3>
        <span class="boxy">subheading blah blah blah</span>
      </h3>
      <h1>
        <span class="boxy">title</span>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer, it works well so I gave you a +1 but I accepted the other answerer as he answered a minute before you. Sorry, thanks for the reply though.

Comment: No worries - I noticed that as I posted. Glad you got the solution.